# Angular Generating New Page Routes (and pages) Dynamically

Tags: angular, routes, single-page-application

I am still getting used to this concept of single page application. I have an old jsp form application that has multiple pages. The number of pages it has is determined on what a user selects in the UI (dynamically creating more webpages). I am trying to rewrite it in angular 13

I was wondering if there is a way to do something similar. I know that I can set the routes the my app.routes.ts, but what if we don't know how many routes (or webpage urls) there will be in the beginning of the app? and I want to create new routes (and pages) on the fly  like the jsp app which is determined by user input? I will just use a bunch of generic components to populate the pages of these new routes.

Does this also go in contradiction to the SPA ideas?

Answer (score 0):

based on what i understood, you have lots of pages with the same behavior, and different content right? if its your case you need to do this.

1.create a component that reads id form route if you do not know how to do that read angular router document(you can find in in google)

2.config your routes and test it

3. create a service and config it to provide your content based on id that u get from route then load the content in that component

Comment: This is for pagination in a list. I am looking for traditional webpage1 -> webpage2 -> webpage3 etc

Each webpage in my example is webpage would contain different content. Thats why I am talking about the routing and specifically for url routing.

Comment: @coloradoman im gonna edit my answer soon

Comment: @Alfred this is irrelevant. I guess you need to edit beforesomeone downvoting your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have also been thinking of using a tabbed interface instead of having many pages so everything kinda stays on a "single page". I am also thinking the number of tabs could get messy if there are a lot of them.
The idea would be to add a new tab based on what the user selects.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that your question has two dimensions: UI and Logic.

1- How you will define your UI that's your personal choice. But there are multiple options (patterns) to go with. Check [Angular Material Components](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) for example on how to organise your web app.

2-Yes you can have dynamic parts in your application URL. Angular allows you to define dynamic segments based on user navigation. Please [read more on common routing tasks](https://angular.io/guide/router#common-routing-tasks) on the Angular documentation

Comment: So you can add to the routes table at run time? I guess I could add a route, and then navigate to it based on a user's input?
I would just say Routes.push(  { path: 'test', component: AutocompleteDisplayExampleComponent })?
And then do     this._router.navigate(["/test"])?

Comment: In your routes object you have to define a place holder for the dynamic value segment (parameter) such as `items/:item_id`. In the component that will be associated with this route that has a dynamic segement, the segement `item_id` will be defined at runtime. For example, you have a list of items under the route name `items` and you want to see item number `254`. The route will become as follows: `items/254`. You can take from there.

Comment: I will definitely consider this.
Does navigating to a new page break the idea of SPA?

Comment: No not at all. The concept of SPA is based on the idea of single web document that has a body which gets updated based on user interaction without the need to reload the whole pages

Comment: If you think the answer above is convenient and helpful you can accept it to help others now that this puts you on the right direction to resolve your problem

Comment: I decided to go with the tabbed interface. I think it looks better to see the different "pages" as a tab.